# Find optimal set and optimal value for feasible set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I am currently following the course:
EE364A - [Convex Optimization I](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE364A/85)

I have a question about one of the exercises which I have been struggling to solve. It is an optimization problem and should be rather simple but it aint that simple for me.

The exercise is as follows:

4.1 Consider the optimization problem

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad  f_0(x_1,x_2) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad  2x_1 + x_2 >= 1 \\
   & \quad  x_1 + 3x_2 >= 1  \\
   & \quad  x_1 >= 0, x_2 >= 0
\end{align}
Make a sketch of the feasible set. For each of the following objective functions, give the optimal set and the optimal value. 
\begin{align}
\text{(a)} & \quad f_0(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2 \\
\text{(b)} & \quad f_0(x_1,x_2) = -x_1 - x_2 \\
\text{(c)} & \quad f_0(x_1,x_2) = x_1 \\
\text{(d)} & \quad f_0(x_1,x_2) = max\{x_1,x_2\} \\
\text{(e)} & \quad f_0(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 + 9x_2^2
\end{align}
My sketch is just like in the [solution](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw3sol.pdf) so ill just take that.

[Sketch of the feasible set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Jz1.png)

(a) I found this to be x* = [2/5, 1/5] which is the point where the two lines crosses.

(b)-(e) I haven't really figured how to solve. Could you guys give me a hint on how to solve them. The solution gives me the result but I don't understand them.

Would I be able to illustrate this in MATLAB? Or how can I easily see the answers to them?

Comment: draw isolines (a/b/c) or isocurves (d/e)

Comment: How would you draw the isolines or isocurves?

Comment: You draw curves for $f_0(x_1,x_2)=c$ for varying values of $c$.

Comment: Can you do this in Matlab? And can you do this by hand? I cant really find the command in MATLAB for this.

Comment: I dont really understand how you would do it. Can you please tell me that? @LinAlg

Comment: You can do it by hand. For a, you get $x_1+x_2 = c$, or $x_2 = c-x_1$. This is a simple function you can draw for varying $c$.

Comment: Yes I figured that. But how do you draw max(x1, x2)?

Comment: as the top and right side of a square

Comment: As the top and right side of a square? Hmm. What do you mean?